# Status Request from Webhook for PR to main, but not in merge queues?

Tags: git, github-actions, cicd

I have some concourse scripts that run for CICD when we push or do PRs to main. They are triggered from webhooks.

I also currently have a Status check from concourse prior to merge as a requirement on the main branch.

What I was noticing is that the Merge Queue also requires it as well ( since it merges into main ), BUT merge queues are not a part of the webhook.   I want this webhook and status to exist only on the PR itself and not the merge queue aspect.

How do I set this web-hook and status check to ONLY affect PR and not the merge queue workflow?

Right now I have as follows:

- Settings > Branches > main > Require Status Checks before Merging > [Concourse flow name]
- Settings > Webhooks > hook for PR and Push > edit > Individual Events > PR / Pushes

I was thinking that I could maybe do something in .github/actions to set up the status and webhook, but I was not sure if that was a way to set up a trigger and monitor.